# How to dynamically add Checkbox-Buttons to userform in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, checkbox

I have a userform with 5 checkbox buttons for 5 pdf versions.
Well, when the user calls the userform, then the userform initializes 5 checkbox buttons to select one of them. At the moment, the code is very static and not so good.

Here the example:

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
  Do Until rs.EOF Or i = 5
     Select Case i
       Case Is = 0
         frmOne.Version5.Visible = True
         frmOne.Version5.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         frmOne.Version5.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
       Case Is = 1
         frmOne.Version4.Visible = True
         frmOne.Version4.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         frmOne.Version4.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
       Case Is = 2
         frmOne.Version3.Visible = True
         frmOne.Version3.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         frmOne.Version3.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
       Case Is = 3
         frmOne.Version2.Visible = True
         frmOne.Version2.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         frmOne.Version2.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
       Case Is = 4
         frmOne.Version1.Visible = True
         frmOne.Version1.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         frmOne.Version1.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
    End Select
    i = i + 1
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

To much code I think. So my intention was to define it like the example below, but this doesn't work:

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
    For i = 1 To 5
      With frmOne
         .Version & i &.Visible = True
         .Version & i &.Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         .Version & i &.tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
      End With
      rs.MoveNext
    Next i
End If
```

Do have anyone an idea how could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the `Controls` collection using the name:

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
    For i = 1 To 5
      With frmOne.Controls("Version" & i)
         .Visible = True
         .Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         .tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
      End With
      rs.MoveNext
    Next i
End If
```

To actually add the controls at runtime too:

```
Do While not rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
      With frmOne.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Version" & i, True)
         .Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
         .tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
      End With
      rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: And what is, when the checkboxes not predefined in the userform? How can I add the checkboxes to the userform?

Comment: Use the `Add` method of the controls collection.

Comment: You mean just to define `With frmOne.Controls.Add("Version" & i)...`

Comment: When I do this, I'm getting the runtime error: '-2147221005 (800401f3)' invalid class string

Comment: Use the `Left`, `Top`, `Height` and `Width` properties.

Comment: More interesting is how can I define the click event for these checkbox versions?

Comment: That is a completely different question and should be asked as such please.

Answer (score 1):

go like follows:

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
    For i = 1 To 5
        With frmOne.Controls("Version" & i) '<~~ use Controls collection of Userform object
           .Visible = True
           .Caption = rs!versNo & "#" & rs!versFrom
           .Tag = rs!versNo & "_" & rs!FiD & ".pdf"
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: look to the comment below!